# Hide/Show content using ActionFilterAttribute/AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: security, model-view-controller, authorization, actionfilterattribute, authorize-attribute

I'm using MVC 2 with futures, and I'm trying to hide/show content based on role.  Is there a way with ActionFilterAttribute or AuthorizeAttribute if the authentication fails to not show the controller child action all through attributes?  Or is all I can do with those attributes is redirect or throw up an error message?  I just need the child action to return nothing basically if it fails the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just assign the result to a blank ActionResult.

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult();
        }